# Totally Disable ViewState in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, viewstate, webforms

In an ASP.NET 4 Web Forms Web Application I want to completely disable `ViewState` for a `TextBox` control. I've searched the internet but couldn't find an answer that solved my problem.

So far I have tried setting the `Page` directive like this:

```
EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false"
```

I've also set the `TextBox` control like this:

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false"
```

Normally these 2 settings should be enough for disabling `ViewState`, but it is not.

Then, I wrote the following in the page's code-behind file:

```cs
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state) { }

protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    return null;
}
```

This resulted in the `ViewState` value in the HTML to be null, but when I press the submit button, the value in the `TextBox` is still remembered by the browser.

How can I disable this functionality?

Comment: Are you using the asp:TextBox or a custom server control (i.e. MyTextBox)? What you could always do is remove the contents of the TextBox on Page_PreRender() event. **UPDATE** Even better, you could override the TextBox.LoadPostData() method in your own server control. More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx (look at "Stage 3 - Load Postback Data") http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.loadpostdata.aspx

Comment: I use <asp:TextBox .../> not a custom control. That would be a good idea but i am also a little curious on how i could finally disable ViewState. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how ViewState is used.

See [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) for a full explanation.  To quote:

> ViewState is not responsible for the population of values that are
>   posted such as by TextBox controls (although it does play an important
>   role)

Comment: It is a very detailed and helpful article. Didn't have in mind that viewstate can be so confusing.